# Issues with multi-colored bar chart

Tags: r

I'm trying to color a bar chart and can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. My data looks like

```
x <- structure(list(A = 0.98, B = 0.46, C = 0.81, D = 0.66, E = 0.76, 
F = 0.42, G = 0.58, H = 0.99, I = 0.57, J = 0.81, K = 0.6, 
L = 0.55, M = 0.4, N = 0.99, O = 0.6, P = 0.75, Q = 0.93, 
R = 0.77), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R"), row.names = "dat", class = "data.frame")
```

and I have a flag that I want to use for color-coding. So I've tried

```
col_code=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
cols = c("red","blue")[col_code+1]
barplot(as.matrix(x),col=cols)
```

However, this creates a single solid color (whatever the second color is). I can't for the life of me tell the difference between what I'm doing here and the solutions in the 10 other guides for solving this problem that I've found, and I'd really appreciate it if someone here could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are `col_flag` and `col_code` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Eumenedies edited it to be correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `barplot` function handles matrices pretty specifically. If you read the help `?barplot` you'll see:

> If height is a matrix and beside is FALSE then each bar of the plot corresponds to a column of height, with the values in the column giving the heights of stacked sub-bars making up the bar. If height is a matrix and beside is TRUE, then the values in each column are juxtaposed rather than stacked.

What this means, is that matrices are used to create stacked barplots with each column being a new bar and each row being a stacked subsection. So, when you set the `col` parameter` what you are actually setting is the colours of sequentially stacked sub-bars. If you add some more rows to your matrix you'll see something that looks kinda like
[image: coloured stacked barplot]

What you want is to set `beside = TRUE`

```
barplot(height = as.matrix(x), col = cols, beside = TRUE)
```

or use a vector, rather than a matrix i.e.

```
barplot(height = as.vector(t(x), col = cols)
```

To give the image:

[image: correctly coloured barplot]

Alternatively, you could use [`ggplot`](http://ggplot2.org/) for making graphs

Comment: Thank you! This was fantastically helpful. I couldn't understand how I was getting this behavior without an error (i.e. where was the red?), but your explanation and example is very clear. I've used the `beside` syntax because it maintained the column labels without any more fussing with the data structure. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.